# primefaces poll dynamic interval

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I wrote example code like this :

```
@ViewScoped
@Named
public class SampleBean implements Serializable {

    private int interval = 1;


    public void execute() {
        switch (interval) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1 Executed ...");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2 Executed ...");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3 Executed ...");
                break;
        }
    }

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }
}
```

and this xhtml :

```
<h:form>
        <p:selectOneButton value="#{sampleBean.interval}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
        </p:selectOneButton>

        <p:poll interval="#{sampleBean.interval}" listener="#{sampleBean.execute}" id="poll"/>

    </h:form>
```

I want to update interval time of primefaces poll component dynamically but not changed with my example code . sleep always executed every 1 second .
What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `p:poll` component to refetch it's backing bean values. You can easily accomplish this by invoking a new rendering phase (via PrimeFaces `update` or via `f:ajax` `render`) on the component.

So to make it work, you just have to do something like this,

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{sampleBean.interval}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3"/>
        <f:ajax render="@form"/>
    </p:selectOneButton>
    <p:poll interval="#{sampleBean.interval}" listener="#{sampleBean.execute}" id="poll"/>
</h:form>
```

Notice the `f:ajax` invocation above.

You need to target the enclosing (parent) component to get it to refresh - this is why we are targeting the form instead of the poll component directly.

Comment: Thank you adam : How can render only poll component by id ? I used render="poll" but receive error !

Comment: Found : set id on form and use <f:ajax render="myForm poll"/>

Comment: No, that would update the children of the form. Specifying `render="myForm poll"` tells the ajax tag (and JSF) to refresh the children of `myForm` and `poll` - so in this particular instance it's the same as specifying `@form`. You target the children of the component - so the solution if you just want to refresh `p:poll` is to enclose it in a component and target that component for the refresh (as stated in the answer already).